# Fill pdf forms and send them as one merged http response in output stream

Tags: spring-mvc, pdf, itext, httpresponse

I have multiple pdf pages having acro form fields which I want to fill and then merge into one pdf file and then pass it to HTTP response header as one OutputStream using iText . Please tell me the solution .

Comment: "Please tell me the solution" is a question that is generally not accepted on StackOverflow. Please show us what you've tried. If you don't know where to start, please [watch this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6YwDME0Fl1c), consult [the documentation](http://developers.itextpdf.com/), For instance: [Using forms for reporting](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/form-examples/using-forms-reporting) **IMPORTANT:** some of those examples show *how not to do it!* Don't just copy/paste them without watching the tutorial or without reading the documentation!

Comment: I've spent a lot of time and money building the offficial web site, providing answers to questions such as [How to merge forms from different files into one PDF?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-merge-forms-different-files-one-pdf) It's frustrating that you didn't find that information, so please tell me what I could do to make sure that other people like you use the site instead of asking an already answered question on StackOverflow. Right now it feels as if I have been wasting time and money on the site. (A possible answer could be "I was too lazy to read the documentation.")

Comment: Hi Bruno , I have gone throught this link but this does not answer my problem . Actually I need to fill separate pages forms which are not identical and then merge them into one output stream so that I can pass it to the HTTP response header .

Comment: Your comment confirms that the answer solves your problem. Filling out and merging forms that are not identical is easier than filling out and merging forms that are identical. Any developer should be able to simplify the example with identical forms so that it works for non-identical forms. Passing a PDF stream to an HTTP response is explained in the answer to [How can I serve a PDF to a browser without storing a file on the server side?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-can-i-serve-pdf-browser-without-storing-file-server-side). Please fix your question.

Comment: Note: you typically send an output stream to an HTTP response object. You can't pass an output stream to an HTTP *header*.